# How to share a directory between ubuntu host and windows guest with kvm?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, shared-folders

I read several posts or articles which deal with this but all give a solution for linux guest. For example :

- [Article on linux-kvm.org](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio)
- [System pass through in KVM/QEMU Libvirt](http://troglobit.com/blog/2013/07/05/file-system-pass-through-in-kvm-slash-qemu-slash-libvirt/)

I also heard about using a samba server or something like that. Does anybody know precisely how to set up a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be quite simple. Right click on the folder in the host that you want to share, then select **Sharing Properties** and give it a name where it asks (this is mandatory). Check the obvious boxes, save configuration, and bam! It is in your guest's network. Just open the file browser and see it in the left column by clicking on your host computer's name.